# Can't return true using gmaps geocode asynchronous method inside a synchronous method

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, google-maps-api-3

I have an asynchronous method that calls google maps geocoder to get an address. It's in a validation method "LocationValidator" that needs to return true or false. Right now I can't seem to get it to return anything but false. It seems that when the "outside callback" is called it returns false every time even though I'm not returning anything from the "isResults" method.

Here is my code

```js
function LocationValidator(value, element, paras) {

var address = "";
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': value }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

            address = results[0].formatted_address;
            if (isResults("Inside callback", address)) {
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
    isResults("Outside callback", address);
}

function isResults(where, address) {

    if (address != "") {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

geocoding is asynchronous so you are calling `isResults("Outside callback", address);` before any response will be returned.

At that time address equals `""` which would trigger your validation error to show.

Also note that you declare `var address` twice and due to scopes they will be separate variables. You should remove `var` from version inside the geocode callback closure or not use the first version at all.

Currently the outer variable `address` will never change

Comment: But I'm not returning anything on calling isResults("Outside callback", address);, I thought the validator will look for a true or false to be returned?